# Non-EU citizen with EU Blue Card working outside EU but with address in Germany

Tags: germany, residency, blue-card, foreign-employment

I am in a weird situation here and need your advice. I am an EU Blue Card holder and I currently work for a company in Germany. I would like to go back to my home country but remain working remotely for this German company. I would still pay German taxes, healthcare, etc.

Am I correct to say that if I have an address in Germany (let's say I rent an apartment even though I don't physically live there) but am abroad, my EU Blue Card is still valid? Because in theory I never left Germany since I "live" there. Do they check passport stamps or only if I had residence registered?

Comment: Why do you think renting an apartment makes you "living" there?

Comment: Leaving the country for 6 consecutive months inalidates your residence permission ([§51 AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__51.html)).

Answer (score 1):

No, you're incorrect about that. If you are not present in the country, do not have accommodation, etc. you do not “live” there. Failing to deregister from your previous address or registering an address where you are not living as your main residence just adds a separate offense to the mix (that in itself is punishable by heavy fines even if you were a German citizen and did not need a residence permit).